# Squid dstdom_regex not working

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

I want to deny all URL beginning by iso, in squid 3.2.3
So, I've put in squid.conf:

```
  acl torrent_sites dstdom_regex -i iso
  acl music_sites dstdom_regex -i music
```

and my http control like:

```
  http_access allow localhost
  http_access allow localnetp1
  http_access deny torrent_sites localnetp1
  http_access deny music_sites
  http_access deny ftp_request
  http_access deny localnetp1 norm_conn
  http_access deny all
```

but i can enter to the page isohunt.com, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are processed in order.  Once an `http_access allow` has been reached processing stops and the connection is permitted.  What is the `localnetp1` ACL doing?  Does that happen to be a `src` acl with a list of all your IP addresses perhaps?

Your rules generally be ordered like thisgo

```
# all the specific denies first
http_access deny asdf
http_access deny sdfa
# any explicit allows
http_access allow dfas
# deny everything else
http_access deny all
```

Comment: yes, localnetp1 is a src with a list o ip addresses.

Comment: Right, so my answer applies, and you should try re-ordering your ACLs.